# Does my phone have a front facing camera AND / OR a microphone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building an application that will need to know these answers:

Does the device have a front facing camera?

Does the device have a microphone?

Is there a bool value I can use to check these? I won't need to use them right yet, but, I am planning on using them in the future soon, so, I am trying to incorporate these.

What I have tried:

Searching Google

Searching Stackoverflow for similar questions

Searching answers.yahoo.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [IsCameraTypeSupported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.camera.iscameratypesupported%28v=vs.92%29.aspx):

```
if(PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.FrontFacing))
   Debug.WriteLine("Front Facing camera exists");
```

There are currently two enumerations for [CameraType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.cameratype%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) (`Primary` and `FrontFacing`)

All phones have a microphone, so you don't need to check for that.